# Twilio: generatng a Capability token using javascript/JQuery

Tags: javascript, twilio

Is there any way to create a Twilio client's capability token using javascript? I know that you can create one in php but cannot find an example of generating one in a .js file.

Answer (score 1):

Twilio evangelist here.

I believe there are JavaScript ports of the [JSON Web Token](http://self-issued.info/docs/draft-ietf-oauth-json-web-token.html) spec, but that said creating the token in JavaScript on the client is not a good idea because you would have to put your Twilio AccountSid and AuthToken in the JavaScript, which is not secure.  That is why we encourage you to generate the capability token only on a server (Javascript on the server is fine) and send it to the client.

I recently wrote a [blog post](http://www.twilio.com/blog/2013/07/simple-twilio-scripts-using-webscript-io.html) that shows how to use a service call [webscript.io](https://www.webscript.io/) to generate tokens without having to write much code or stand up a server yourself.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hey Devin, you are referring to Javascript running inside a client's browser, correct? There shouldn't be anything inherently wrong with creating the capability token on a server that is running Javascript?